# Sort file "foo" and use redirection ">" to save output into the same "foo" file

Tags: io-redirection

i have a text file ~/foo:

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
```

i use `sort foo -u`, and that works correctly. I can use redirection operator ">" to save output into other file (f.e.: `sort foo -u > bar`), but when i want to save it into original file `sort foo -u > foo` i get empty file as a result. Why that has happend?

Comment: Related: [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408) — [Warning regarding ‘>’](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/23408).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `>` is interpreted by shell and it opens an empty file named `foo`.  You will need to save the output to another file and rename it to the original if you want to keep the same file name.

Comment: No, you don't need to use another file; just use `sort foo -o foo`.